# How to make changes only for list that have sublist?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list. And i want to delete the link addresses for `li` that have `ul > li` and to keep the links for the lists without sub-lists.. 
For example: "Home" should be a link, and *"FRANCHISING"* should open in page (like it does now) and not sending me to another page..

http://jsfiddle.net/yj6pL160/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > ul > li > ul').hide();
    if ($('#nav > ul > li').has('ul')) {
        $('#nav > ul > li > a').removeAttr("href");
    }
    $('#nav > ul > li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this function:

It selects all list elements that have a list as a child. Then selects the direct anchor children (so not the anchors in the sublist) and remove the href attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > ul > li > ul').hide();
    $('#nav > ul > li').has('ul').find('>a').removeAttr("href");

    $('#nav > ul > li').click(function () {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yj6pL160/2/)